# quickest way to get all nodes (recursively) in JSoup doc

Tags: java, scala, recursion, jsoup, nodes

I'd like to get all nodes in a JSoup doc.  What's the best way to do this (in Java or Scala?)

Thanks

Comment: Have you debugged the different methods to achieve this and come to any conclusion or idea? As I'm looking through the source code right now, I don't think there is much difference between them actually, thus performance should be a minor issue if one at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getAllElements()` works, and produces the same results as `document.select("*")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*` selector:

```
Elements elements = document.select("*");
```